# Solving $y = xc^x + x + 1$, where c is a constant

Tags: calculus

How do you solve $xc^x + x + 1 = 0$ for $x$, where $c$ is a constant?

Comment: Doesn't look like something you can solve neatly, or even use the Lambert function on...

Comment: small comment on existence..for sufficiently large negative values of $x$, $y$ is negative and for some positive values of $x$, $y$ is positive, since the function is continuous it seems to have a solution...

Comment: @Dinesh:  I think your statements require positive $c$.

Comment: @Henry yes..I missed that.

Comment: Given the tag "algebra-precalculus", I am inclined to answer "You just don't.".

Comment: Title $\ne$ body. Do you want $y$ in there, or do you want zero? Please decide and edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't exist a simple formula, in terms of elementary functions, for finding the roots of functions of this form.

If you need the root for particular $c$ (and $c\neq 0, 1$) you will need to approximate the root, for instance by plotting the function and looking for $x$-intercepts, or asking [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5Bx%202%5Ex%20%2b%20x%20%2b%201%20==0,x%5D). There also exist advanced numerical techniques, such as [Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), that you could use to very accurately approximate roots of functions yourself.

Comment: Are you saying Newton's Method is more advanced than Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: No. But if you're a precalculus student, using Alpha as a black box to plot and find the root is a reasonable approach to the problem, while understanding and implementing Newton's method is likely not (unless your precalc class was a lot more interesting than mine!) I've tried to clean up the wording of the answer.